# Azure Service Bus - Subscriptions and DLQ

Tags: java, azure, publish-subscribe, azureservicebus

I have recently started working on Azure Service Bus module which is currently used in our project. The current model is that, we send message to a topic and the topic has multiple subscriptions. There is no filter for subscriptions and the subscribers consume it(Currently not looking to add filters).

Question: Let's say there is 1 topic and 3 subscriptions. The message sent to topic is broadcasted to all subscriptions and applications from two subscriptions consume it. Application for the third subscription goes down and the message is not consumed.

1. What happens to the message from the 3rd subscription, will it be sent to Dead Letter Queue after TTL
2. Is there a way to find out, for which subscription the message wasn't consumed

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to the message from the 3rd subscription, will it be sent to Dead Letter Queue after TTL

If subscription is configured to dead-letter expired messages, yes, that's what will happen.

> Is there a way to find out, for which subscription the message wasn't consumed

You shouldn't do that. Topics and subscriptions are intended to implement Pub/Sub pattern and is about **decoupling** the senders from the receivers.

Comment: 1. What will happen if we haven't configured the DLQ, will it be removed from service bus after TTL
On a separate note, doesn't DLQ exist along with Topic ? Should It be configured to receive messages if we are not forcefully moving it to DLQ?

Comment: DLQ exists for each queue and topic. It's the attribute on the entity that needs to be set to true to dear-lettet the expired messages.