# How DLQ works in Azure Service bus queue?

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

I am learning how DLQ works in `Azure service bus queue`. i.e., unconsumed messages will be in DLQ. I have enabled dead lettering (`deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration`) on message expiration.

**References:**

- [Azure Service Bus - Subscriptions and DLQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444791/azure-service-bus-subscriptions-and-dlq)
- [Azure Service Bus - *move* message from DLQ to main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041052/azure-service-bus-move-message-from-dlq-to-main)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/enable-dead-letter

**AMR template:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-namespace-queue

**Questions:**

- If `deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration` is enabled, would DLQ be available for that queue (like below screenshot)?
- If yes, how can I process messages from DLQ? (I guess I can view such messages here but not sure what will happen next)

[image]

My goal is to create a queue with DLQ where unprocessed message can be processed at some point and what is the best way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration is enabled, would DLQ be available for that queue?

Dead-letter queue is always there for queues and subscriptions, unrelated to how you configure your entity.

> If yes, how can I process messages from DLQ?

Up to you. You can peek DLQ-ed messages, recieve and process, etc. It really depends on how you want to handle those dead-lettered messages in the context of your system.

Comment: My goal is, if something is in DLQ, then process it immediately (similar to regular queue).

Comment: Assuming that processing will be different than the original logic, you'd be using some compute to accomplish that. For example, Azure Functions. Your function would react to the DLQ-ed messages as they arrive.

Comment: Ah, I see. Same way lambda trigger works in AWS. Let me look into this. Thank you @sean.